# Transofrm a template (html/css/js) in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I had a template in HTML/CSS/JS and now I want the transform in Laravel.
I executed the command `composer install` and I have the error message

*Composer could not find a composer.json file in C:\wamp64\www\elec
To initialize a project, please create a composer.json file as described in the https://getcomposer.org/ "Getting Started" section*

Must I do obligatorily a `composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel myProjet` for example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to create a laravel project you sure have to execute that line. Or if you want to install it in an existing folder, then replace `myProject` with `.`

So inside the folder run this:

`composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel .`

Next steps are to create your blade view using your html file, and place your css and js files within your resources js and css folders of your laravel project.

Comment: hello I have an error message =>  [InvalidArgumentException]
  Project directory ./ is not empty. I don't understand ,??

Comment: you probably have files already in the folder that you are trying to create the laravel project. So I would suggest you make the installation on an empty project, and then move your template files in the newly created project